# How to use accelerometer to press a button in android?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am trying to use accelerometer to press a button in android studio for my dice app. Does anyone know how to hook it up to a button, so that when I shake my phone the dice will roll? I've tried to use SensorEventListener but couldn't get it to work. Thanks for any feedback/suggestion.
PS. I'm a noob.

Here is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button rollButton;
    rollButton = findViewById(R.id.rollButton);

    final ImageView leftDice = findViewById(R.id.diceLeft);
    final ImageView rightDice = findViewById(R.id.diceRight);
    final ImageView topDice = findViewById(R.id.diceTop);

    final int [] diceArray = {
            R.drawable.perspective_dice_one,
            R.drawable.perspective_dice_two,
            R.drawable.perspective_dice_three,
            R.drawable.perspective_dice_four,
            R.drawable.perspective_dice_five,
            R.drawable.perspective_dice_six,
    };

    rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("Dice", "You pressed the button!");

            Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

            int number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);
            Log.d("Dice", "The random number is: " + number);

            leftDice.setImageResource(diceArray[number]);

            number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);
            rightDice.setImageResource(diceArray[number]);

            number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);
            topDice.setImageResource(diceArray[number]);


        }
    });



}
```

}

Comment: What data have you been able to get from the accelerometer? Also, you should "call a method", not "click a button"

Comment: I couldn't get any data, i couldn't get SensorEventListenor to work.
I tried to do rollbutton.setSensorEventListenor, but i had an error instead.

Comment: It might be useful to see what error you got and what code you tried